# Use variable as part of resource name

Tags: c#, resources

I have a `Picturebox` named `pictureBoxLoadingMsg` and am trying to set it's background image inside a timer. Each time the timer ticks, I want to change the image of the picturebox.

I am trying to use a variable as part of the resource name. Examples of the image file names are loading1 and loading2.

I want to use the variable `i` (which will be an incrementing integer e.g 1, 2, 3) as part of the resource name. I have tried concatenating it to 'loading' (the first part of the resource name), but the code has errors and will not run - it says:

> Resources does not contain a definition for loading

```
int i = 0;
private void TimerLoadingMessages_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   pictureBoxLoadingMsg.Image = Properties.Resources.loading + i; 
   // should result in loading1 on the first tick, loading2 on the second tick and so on
   i++;
}
```

Comment: Looking up Resources also works with a string as key. You can build that key out of a fix string and some number. But it won't work as in the example. What is the sum of an image object and an integer supposed to be after all? Cannot test it right now, but something like `Properties.Resources[$"loading{i}"]` may work.

Comment: @Fildor Added a comment to my code, it shouldn't perform a calculation - just concatenate the value of the variable to 'loading'

Comment: I get that. But `Properties.Resources.loading` will get the _value_, not the key. So you end up with "object of type Image + number of type integer", while you want "lookup object of type Image from resources with key "loadingN" ". Hope it makes sense.

Comment: @Fildor Tried your suggestion, but it says `Resources is a type, which is not valid in the given context`

Comment: Can you add the code you tried to the question? You are on WinForms, right?

Comment: @Fildor Yes WinForms, and just used `Properties.Resources[$"loading{i}"]` from your previous comment

Comment: I can only test very rudimentary and I could swear, I have used it like that before, but anyway: Try `Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject($"loading{i}"])` you will probably need to cast.

Comment: @Fildor You're right it mentions about casting, but I'm not sure how to do this lol

Comment: `PictureBox.Image` is of Type `Image` if I remember correctly. So if your Resource is an Image (and I do expect so), then just do `pictureBoxLoadingMsg.Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject($"loading{i}"]);`

Comment: @Fildor That works great! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compose your key, then lookup the value:

```
pictureBoxLoadingMsg.Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject($"loading{i}"]);
```

where `i` is the running index and `"loading"` whatever the fix part of the key is.
`GetObject` will return an object, so you need to cast to the actual type.

Please also read and consider the remarks given in the docs: [ResourceManager.GetObject(string)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcemanager.getobject?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

There is too less info!

- what type is pictureBoxLoadingMsg?
- The error says that the problem is on resources, Resources are done right?

Try some:

```
pictureBoxLoadingMsg.Image = string.Format({0}{1}, Properties.Resources.loading, i);
```

Comment: Won't work. You format {0} = Image.ToString() and {1} = integer. You'd want to compose the _key_, then lookup into resources. `Properties.Resources.loading` is just syntactic sugar for `Properties.Resources["loading"]` (basically)

Comment: ^^ Correcting myself : shortcut for `(Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("loading")`.